# Proposal to reopen "Analyze traffic by AS"

Tags: discussion

A recent question asking for recommendations on analysing traffic by ASN was closed for Resource Request, against topic rules.

Given this is an important non-beginner networking problem, easily achieved with Wireshark, I've edited the question to ask if it's possible "with standard tools".  I'll put the Wireshark answer up if reopened.

[Analyze Network Traffic by Autonomous System Number?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56152/analyze-network-traffic-by-autonomous-system-number)

Please could you reopen this?

Thanks.

Comment: I see it reopened, thanks Moderator.

Comment: perhaps it's an idea to convert that comment to an answer and accept it, so this question can be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it reopened in January, thanks Moderator.